# TSQL concatenate parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, concatenation

I'm attempting to determine why my stored procedure will not operate correctly.
The issue is when I utilize a concatenated parameter.  When finished, I will have 6 or 7 of these, each built upon the last.
I've tried every variation including =, like, %, spaces, no spaces, and cannot come up with the correct syntax to make this operational.
I have also did a 'hard coded' test, and it works fine, so the data is correct.
HELP!  Thanks

Here's the code -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rspSCLTEST]

(@RRID as varchar(4),
@State as varchar(2),
@Sub as varchar(75))
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL as varchar(4000)

SET @SQL = @State

--add the subdivision to the where statement
If @Sub = 'ALL'
SET @SQL = @SQL
ELSE
 SET @SQL += ' AND (C.SubDivision = '+ @Sub + ')'


SELECT C.CRID, C.DOT, C.RR, C.Pref, C.MP, C.Division, C.SubDivision, C.City, C.Street,
    C.State, C.County, C.RestrictedCounty, C.Remarks, C.SpecialInstructions, C.Route, C.ThirdAppRequired,
    C.MainTrks, C.OtherTrks, C.OnSpur, C.MaxSpeed, C.SubContracted, C.FenceEncroachment, C.Lat, C.Long,
    C.PropertyType, C.WarningDevice,C.Surface, C.ROWNE, C.ROWNW, C.ROWSE, C.ROWSW, C.ROWWidth, C.ExtNE,
    C.ExtNW, C.ExtSE, C.ExtSW, C.TempActive, C.PCO, A.App1Date, A.App1Cut, A.App1Spray, A.App1Inspect, 
    A.App2Date, A.App2Cut, A.App2Spray, A.App2Inspect, A.App3Date, A.App3Cut, A.App3Spray, A.App3Inspect

    FROM Crossings AS C LEFT OUTER JOIN AppData AS A ON C.CRID = A.CRID
    WHERE (C.DeletedCrossing = 0) AND (C.RR = @RRID)
    AND C.State = @SQL


END
```

Comment: you need to work on your question first, post some code and I think you are trying to concatenate parameters, if so use `+` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing dynamic SQL with parameter replacement.  Try something like this:

```
and c.state = @state and (@sub = 'ALL' or c.subdivision = @sub)
```

The way you had this written, you were checking for:

```
and c.state = '<state> and c.subdivision = @sub'
```

That is, the second clause is not being interpreted as a *clause*, it is being interpreted as part of the state.

Comment: the issue here is, that if @sub = 'All', I don't need the parameter included at all. "all" means give me all of the subdivisions, not just the one I'm asking for.  I've also attempted to say If Sub = 'All' SQL = SQL + '(C.SubDivision = ' + C.SubDivision + ')'

Comment: @CindyBrozyno . . . that is what this logic does.

Comment: How would this work when you have a field that is datatype BIT, and not varchar? for instance - Field= subcontracted. The user can choose to see all that ARE subcontracted, all that ARE NOT subcontracted, or ALL records.

Comment: @CindyBrozyno . . . something like `field = (case when @t = 'subcontracted' then 1 when @t = 'all' then field else 0 end)`.  Same idea but with three values.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
SET @SQL += ' AND (C.SubDivision = '+ @Sub + ')'
```

And this line:

```
AND C.State = @SQL
```

appear suspect.  I can only make assumptions about your data, but it looks like you've got two different objects: State, and Sub-division.

What kind of data is in C.State?  Is it just state abbreviations?  (OR, WA, MO, MN, AZ, etc.).  If so, you'll never get a positive result out of `WHERE C.State = WA123` (assuming '123' is a sub-division value).

In any case, could you do something like this? -->

```
WHERE C.State = @state AND C.Subdivision = @sub
```